# Can EntityFramework connect to any data provider?

Tags: entity-framework, dataprovider

We have a data source accessible from an XML RPC web service where we can send CRUD commands.

Is it possible to use this with EF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unless you write your own provider. EF has very limited set of [providers available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865352/a-list-of-entity-framework-providers-for-various-databases). All these providers targets relational databases.

Comment: Is is possible to write a provider? I mean, for someone outside Microsoft. Is there any docs available? How feasible would it be?

Comment: It is a lot of work and it will probably not work because EF provider targets database and works with ADO.NET classes like DbCommand, DbConnection, etc.